# How to write json object to Azure Data Explorer

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-data-explorer

I have seen sample codes for ingesting data from streams or from files

example: https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-node/blob/master/packages/azure-kusto-ingest/example.js
,

but didn't see anything related to simple JSON objects.

Should I convert my json object to a stream or is there any direct way

Answer (score -1):

Yes, serialize your JSON object to a stream/file/blob and ingest from there.